# How do I organize this information in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an application and using SQLite for a database, but I never used a database class.
I'm trying to figure out how to organize the following information:

> A User Class: Has a name, two integer fields, and a LIST of groups,
>
> A Group class: Has a name, a double field, and a LIST of users
>
> A user will also eventually have to have some sort of authentication
>   (username/password) field but I plan to deal with that later.

If you could help me think through how to organize this information in SQLite, that would be great.

Comment: By the way, storing passwords in plaintext is not recommended. I understand that you are just learning, but if you want to do it "correctly", see [How not to store passwords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) for a brief overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables can be organised as follows,

Table `User_tbl`

```
--------------------------------------------------
_ID     int         primary key
--------------------------------------------------
name    text        name of user
--------------------------------------------------
field1  int         int field 1
--------------------------------------------------
field2  int         int field 2
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table `Group_tbl`

```
--------------------------------------------------
_ID     int         primary key
--------------------------------------------------
name    text        name of group
--------------------------------------------------
field   double      double field
--------------------------------------------------
```

As per @cricket_007s answer, you need another table that links both these fields,

Table `User_groups_tbl`

```
--------------------------------------------------
_ID         int         primary key
--------------------------------------------------
user_id     int         _ID value from User_tbl
--------------------------------------------------
group_id    int         _ID value from Group_tbl
--------------------------------------------------
```

A `INNER JOIN` query like,

```
SELECT User_tbl._ID, User_tbl.name, Group_tbl._ID, Group_tbl.name, User_groups_tbl.user_id, User_groups_tbl.group_id
FROM User_tbl, Group_tbl, User_groups_tbl
INNER JOIN User_tbl.User_tbl._ID ON User_groups_tbl.User_groups_tbl.user_id
INNER JOIN Group_tbl.Group_tbl._ID ON User_groups_tbl.User_groups_tbl.group_id
WHERE User_groups_tbl.user_id = user_id;
```

will yield all groups in the user is in.

Likewise an `INNER JOIN` query like,

```
SELECT User_tbl._ID, User_tbl.name, Group_tbl._ID, Group_tbl.name, User_groups_tbl.user_id, User_groups_tbl.group_id
FROM User_tbl, Group_tbl, User_groups_tbl
INNER JOIN User_tbl.User_tbl._ID ON User_groups_tbl.User_groups_tbl.user_id
INNER JOIN Group_tbl.Group_tbl._ID ON User_groups_tbl.User_groups_tbl.group_id
WHERE User_groups_tbl.group_id = group_id;
```

will yield all users in the a group.

**Explanation for `User_groups_tbl`**

This table is used to store the `many-to-many` relationship between the two tables `User_tbl` and `Group_tbl`. When a user is added to a new group or vice versa, add an entry with the `_ID` of the corresponding group and the `_ID` of the corresponding user in this table.

Comment: I guess... But it's a poor design. How would you find the information about all users of a group from a comma separated list? Other than splitting the string, and query for individual IDs?

Comment: Will need work I guess. Can I modify according to your answer?

Comment: @cricket_007 Please check :)

Comment: Looks good, though I'd add the JOIN query to get all usernames in a group

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the User_groups_tbl. Could you give me an example on how to use this?

Comment: This is not the best solution if you want to make scalable app because you will first query for `user_id` for corresponding group and then for each `user_id` you will query again for user details. I have been in same situation and I prefer using ORM over raw query every time because  of cleaner code and reusability.

Comment: @Sarah Edited answer.

Comment: @NiteshVerma I prefer to use an `ORM` based implementation too. This is how the `ORM` also manages `manytomany` relationships under the hood. Hope the edit has solved the need for a second query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, the two tables form a many-many relationship. So, a "good" database design would have 3 tables.

Table 1(User): user_ID(primary key), name, field_1, field_2

Table 2(Group): group_ID(primary key), name, double_Field

Table 3(Relationship): user_ID(foreign key), group_ID(foreign key).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly , you need to deal with the `many-many` relationship between user and group. With SQLite its really difficult to handle that kind of relation. 
I recommend you to use android `ORM` for that such as [Realm Android](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/) which is faster than sqlite and perfect for your need. For many-many relationship, make your models as https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many

Comment: So do you recommend Realm over SQLite? I guess that was a better initial question. Can Realm also handle username/password authentication later on?

Comment: Yes, why not ? I haven't tried it with `Android`. But I have used `ORM` for Web to authenticate. You need to first search for username using User Model and then if found, match password like `if(user.getPassword().equal(input_password))` to `authenticate` user.

Comment: Great! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Codecademy and take the SQL course. Or you could use Realm or Cupboard or ActiveAndroid (there's several libraries to ease SQLite development). And, unless you are familiar with writing SQL code, then it's best to use one of those.

Basically, you'll have a User table, Group table, then a UserGroup lookup table (2 columns) that lists the ID values of which user ids belong to which group ids.

This can be seen as a [many-to-many](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship.